# How to debug React Router?

Tags: hyperlink, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use React Router in my react app which is bounded as wordpress plugin and uses flux to fetch api data.

my entry point looks as it follows

```
import React from 'react';
import Workshops  from './components/workshops';
import Workshop  from './components/workshop';
import NotFound  from './components/notfound';
import Router, { Route, DefaultRoute, NotFoundRoute, Redirect, Link } from 'react-router';
import json  from './config.json';
localStorage.clear();
localStorage.setItem('workshops', JSON.stringify(json));

const AppRoutes = (
   <Route path="/" handler={Workshops}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Workshop} />
    <Route name="workshop" path=":slug" handler={Workshop}/>
    <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound} />
  </Route>
);

Router.run(AppRoutes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
  React.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('workshop-booker'));
});
```

than in my Workshops component I make some links to a given route, I have hash changes but the routed component does not getting fired.

```
<h3> <Link to="workshop" params={{slug: workshop.slug }}> {workshop.title.rendered }</Link></h3>
```

Comment: What are you looking to debug?

Comment: why the called route does not getting fired, in the example above I would expect on hash change that the worksop component would output on slug a new view

Comment: I want to debug it too, but server side with a `ReactRouter.createMemoryHistory(pagePath)`. B.t.w. in version 1 and 2 it should be `component=` not `handler=` — is that your problem perhaps? (& `name=` is gone) and lots of other stuff has changed too

Comment: I found between a solution -> redux devtools

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can wrap your Router with a DebugRouter which will print the navigation actions made:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from 'components/Login'
import DefaultComponent from 'components/DefaultComponent'

class DebugRouter extends BrowserRouter {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log('initial history is: ', JSON.stringify(this.history, null,2))
    this.history.listen((location, action)=>{
      console.log(
        `The current URL is ${location.pathname}${location.search}${location.hash}`
      )
      console.log(`The last navigation action was ${action}`, JSON.stringify(this.history, null,2));
    });
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DebugRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/" name="Home" component={DefaultComponent} />
        </Switch>
      </DebugRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

[link to the gist](https://gist.github.com/moshemal/540ccb312b3d9941463789eff3c565a4)

Comment: That solution may be working but unfortunately for me I no longer have my redirection problem when I encapsulate the `Switch` component in a `BrowserRouter`. Edit: my problem was because of a `history.push` in my code, that method apparently annihilated the `history.push` command.

Comment: I have recently upgraded to react-router-dom@6.3.0 (don't know if that's important). But I'm getting an error: `react-dom.development.js:14985 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor DebugRouter cannot be invoked without 'new'`

Comment: Oh, I'm guessing it's because I use the function structure instead of class structure.

Answer (score 26):

I made my DebugRouter for functional components

```
const DebugRouter = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
  const { location } = useHistory()
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    console.log(
      `Route: ${location.pathname}${location.search}, State: ${JSON.stringify(location.state)}`,
    )
  }

  return children
}

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Layout>
        <Route
          render={() => {
            return (
              <DebugRouter>
                <Switch>
                  <Redirect exact from="/" to={...} />
                  // <Route/> should be here

                  <Redirect from="*" to={...} />
                </Switch>
              </DebugRouter>
            )
          }}
        />
      </Layout>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Comment: For `"react-router-dom": "^6.8.0"` I had to change `const { location } = useHistory()` to `const location = useLocation();` where `useLocation` is imported from `"react-router-dom"`.

Comment: @JillAndMe could you add all imports to your code snippet, to make it easier to get it to work? Thanks~

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

class RouterDebugger extends Component {
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        console.log('componentWillUpdate',nextProps, nextState)
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log('componentDidUpdate',prevProps)

    }

    render() {
        return null
    }
}

export default withRouter(RouterDebugger)
```

And insert this component in any place you want to debug.
You can pass a prop with some identifier 
i hope this help you

Answer (score -4):

You can use the following code to debug React Router:

```
console.log(this.props.location)
console.log(this.props.match)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: not clear where this should go, I get errors just putting it into the app's render method. addmittedly typescript so it is finding `undefined` more clearly:  `Property 'location' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.  TS2339
`